# How to write custom C++ ops which update resource variables?

Tags: c++, tensorflow

I'm trying to update optimizers like the ones at https://github.com/openai/blocksparse/blob/master/blocksparse/optimize.py to support parameters stored as resource variables. Looking at the TensorFlow [source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.13/tensorflow/core/kernels/training_ops.cc) for the built-in optimizer ops, it seems necessary to have relatively complicated locking and copy-on-write logic to handle the different states a resource variable could be in. TensorFlow uses helper functions in [tensorflow/core/kernels/training_op_helpers.h](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.13/tensorflow/core/kernels/training_op_helpers.h) to do this, calling `MaybeLockVariableInputMutexesInOrder` and `GetInputTensorFromVariable`.

Unfortunately, `training_op_helpers.h` is not in the public TensorFlow headers, so I can't just `#include` it. Worse, it depends on internal functions that `libtensorflow_framework.so` doesn't even export (notably, [`tensorflow::functor::DenseUpdate`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/dense_update_functor_gpu.cu.cc) for the [copy-on-write](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/8bc394be15a7660f37d4952e151374a646d2f195/tensorflow/core/kernels/training_op_helpers.h#L223)), so copying the headers also doesn't suffice.

Is there an intended way to do this sort of thing? At this point I'm tempted to compile my own fork of TensorFlow that exports these functions. (I guess reimplementing them wouldn't be *too* bad.)

Comment: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/27899